# Changing CSS of elements generated from server-sent events

Tags: jquery, css, server-sent-events

I have a list of items - with different classes - generated from a server-sent event that continuously updates.

Where I have:

```
 <div class="not-server-sent"></div>
 <div id="server-sent">
    <ul>
        <li class="black">Foo</li>
        <li class="white">Bar</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

This jQuery works:

```
 $(".not-server-sent").hide();
```

but these do not:

```
  $(".white").hide();
  $("li.white").hide();
```

How can I dynamically hide server-sent data with Javascript? Thanks!

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue.

Comment: Code seems correct. You should provide fiddle for further investigation.

Comment: I can't get server-sent event data into a fiddle I'm afraid - so am just reliant on finding someone who knows how to do this... :/

Comment: try once this $("#server-sent").find("ul li .white").hide();

Comment: Is this the code you tried with? Maybe there is something more specific in your CSS that overrides it.

Comment: @Rupal or just  `$("#server-sent").hide();` ;)

Comment: @Jeremy $("#server-sent").hide(); this will hide complete div, but for specific li he has to use $("#server-sent").find("ul li .white").hide();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say “server-sent” you mean received with AJAX.

That is an asynchronous call.

The `DOM` gets updated.

So jQuery does — not — know about the elements.

You have to update here.

```
$.ajax(/*code*/)
.success(function(data) {
    $(".white").hide();
}
```

Comment: I'm using a different API actually, but your point was still the key... I've solved it by putting the $(".white").hide() line within the Javascript function accepting the SSE data - rather than as a separate function. Thanks!